# Is using a 'Data Class' a bad idea in this scenario?

Tags: java, design-patterns, anti-patterns

I'm currently working with what you could call legacy code at work. I basically have a class that deals with the workflow and is only instantiated once every time the machine is booted up. Each time a new user uses this machines and logs onto it, a new "session" is started, but we keep the same instance of this class. To keep things simple lets say this machine is a self service machine.

This basically means every time a new user session starts, we need to reset all the flow variables back to their default values.

So normally I would have instance/member variables such as:

```
boolean didUserPressYes;
boolean didUserTakeHisReceipt;
int numberOfInsertedItems;
```

and then a resetVars() method that is called at the start of the flow/user session:

```
public void resetVars() {
 didUserPressYes = false;
 didUserTakeHisReceipt = false;
 numberOfInsertedItems = 0;
}
```

Normally I would just reinstantiate this class and avoid having this resetVars() method. Unfortunately, we are tied to a framework that does not allow us to do this and we must keep the same instance of the class.

In our actual code we have about 12 of these variables, and will almost certainly add more in the future. I can see great potential for bugs where these variables are not properly reset to their default value when each user session starts - especially if someone new comes onto the project and forgets to add his new variables into this resetVars() method.

To work around this issue I have made a WorkflowVariables class that contains these variables and has getters and setters where appropiate, and a couple of small utility methods. At the start of each user session we simply reinstantiate this WorkflowVariables class and can now know for a fact that all the variables have been put back to their default values. No need to worry about certain instance variables not being reset, as we just have one:

```
private WorkFlowVariables workFlowVariables;

public void resetVars() {
    workFlowVariables = new WorkFlowVariables();
}
```

However, after some "code smell" reading, it seems that this what is known as a "Data Class" and is bad practice to implement.

Does anyone see this as being a bad idea in my situation, or is this suitable for this specific situation? Perhaps there is a better way to solve this issue? Am I wrong to be too worried about the potential for bugs if we keep multiple instance variables?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see no issue in your approach. I would do the same more or less. Data Class are not bad as you find them everywhere in Java/.NET programs and several other platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention one class that exists while the program is running.  `Program` might be a good name for the class, but you can think of better.

--- A small aside, but we will come back to your mainline problem ---

You also mention variables who's effective scope is one "session".  I would create a second class, `Session` and refactor until those variables are in that class.  Then initialize the variable within the constructor.

Before you start moving things, put in test cases (as best you can) to verify the correct variable behavior.  After it is moved, clean up those test cases and make them robust.  Test for even stuff you wouldn't normally do, or allow to be done (if you have full control over all the code) like passing null variables, etc.

By doing so, you effectively un-legacy a small part of the code.  Trust me it will be worth it.

--- Ok, not back to our regularly scheduled problem ---

You are right, this path sets up a data class; however, the data is in the right spot, now only the logic is in the wrong spot.

Find blocks of code that access the moved data in clusters.  If accessing data directly, you can do this by making the member private and watching compilation failures across the product, or use an IDE feature.  Keep track of each access looking for patterns of read and write behavior.

Once you identify a pattern of (let's say) read behavior, then create a dummy method in the "data class" with a name that approximates what you think is happening.  Place that method in the remote caller, and them "move" the statements into the method.   Effectively this moves them into the used-to-be data-only class.

Now you have a class with data and some behavior.  Keep working the pattern until you are satisfied that all the "right" behavior is where it should be.  Then check again if your exposed "getter and setter" methods really need public exposure.

keep your tests up to date throughout the whole process, and verify that they also cover the newly created methods.  They are your safety net that you really didn't change anything, except when you meant to change the code.

Good luck.

--- Edited in reply to question ---

```
I will definitely go through my code and have a look to see where that's appropriate - some of the reading I mentioned suggested that. However, I do feel like because the Workflow Class (i.e. "Program class") already contains little/simple logic, that moving more of it over to the WorkFlowVariables ("Session") class for the sake of avoiding a Data Class seems a bit silly?
```

It is only silly if it is done for a silly reason.  You seem to think the reason to move the code has to do with avoiding a smell.  That's not the reason to move the code at all.  The reason to move the code is because it's in the wrong spot.

If I have logic that is separate from my data, then my data must be managed externally.  That is, every time someone wants to do something with my data, it's up to the "someone" to do it in a way that doesn't leave my data internally inconsistent.  This could contain checking that a variable is not null before setting the data class to contain the variable's value, updating exposed values based on a composite of member variables, sending notifications when values change, marking items for "further processing", storing audit log entries, etc.

```
Won't it also tightly couple those classes?
```

That highly depends on where you make the split, and how you go about it.  Refactoring doesn't mean you solve all problems in one go.  It means you modify the code in such a way that you don't change its functionality.  Between refactoring steps you will eventually make code changes.  Those small code changes can be impossible (or at least difficult) to make without the prior refactoring steps, and they can introduce bugs (as any non-refactoring change can).

Oh, and loose coupling is good where you've designed for extensibility.  Loose coupling where nothing is going to be extended is a classic example of wasting resources to write code you are not going to need.

A good example of loose coupling:

1. A workflow engine that can perform an unknown number of Tasks by calling them through an interface.

A bad example of loose coupling:

1. When you need to enforce a contract of steps, but you decide to make them extend a List of steps such that you now need to pre-process the list of steps  to ensure that they meet the contract.  For example, you use your infinitely configurable "work list" class as the basis for a database update routine, but your database updating framework now needs to verify that every "work list" opens and closes the database.

Of course, you can "fix" this with a Database Work List Validator.  Which means you might need a Database Work List "work manager" to ensure the validation happens at each appropriate point in time, etc.  Yes, you can solve the problem this way, but it will be fragile and the code will exhibit poor data locality.

In the latter example, you would have been much better off with a "Database Work List" that hard coded the required open and close steps, with a configurable number of intermediate steps.

Comment: Extremely helpful answer - wasn't expecting anyone to even understand what I meant but it seems you've got it spot on. 

In regards to adding some behaviour into the class I will definitely go through my code and have a look to see where that's appropriate - some of the reading I mentioned suggested that. However, I do feel like because the Workflow Class (i.e. "Program class") already contains little/simple logic, that moving more of it over to the WorkFlowVariables ("Session") class for the sake of avoiding a Data Class seems a bit silly? Won't it also tightly couple those classes?

Comment: I updated the answer to address some of your questions, as best as they can be answered, from this side of the web.

Answer (score 1):

This seems fine and is probably actually the `State` Pattern so a better name for the class might be `SessionState`.

Thinking about it like a State can hide all the variables and conditional logic.  Each different State will have the variables set differently.  Depending on which is more intent revealing for your usecases, transitioning from one state to the next will set variables or setting the variables will transition the state (or both).